# Direction of motion 1

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, vectors, relative-motion

A man on a bike travelling east on straight road at 8km/h sees a car driving north at 60km/h. What is the apparent speed and diretion of motion of car to the cyclist?

Comment: Please show us how far you got on your own.